# Linq for distinct count

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm not sure how to do this, I have this part of a query:

```
let DistinctHits = db.tblTrackerVisits
    .Where()
    .Select(d=>d.IPID)
    .Distinct()
    .Count()
```

There is a table called `db.tblTrackerVisitVariables`:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is modify the query above so that it only counts the distinct records where one of the relating `tblTrackerVisitVariable` records has a `VariableID` of `n`.

An pseudo example that might make it clearer:

```
let DistinctHits = db.tblTrackerVisits
    .Where(d=> db.tblTrackerVisitVariables.where(v=>v.VisitID == d.ID AND v.VariableID == n))
    .Select(d=>d.IPID)
    .Distinct()
    .Count()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following:

```
let DistinctHits = db.tblTrackerVisits
    .Where(d => d.tblTrackerVisitVariables.Any(v => v.VariableID == n))
    .Select(d => d.IPID)
    .Distinct()
    .Count()
```